# Turn off compilation of files during Minification during Dojo build

Tags: javascript, build, dojo, minify, rhino

I am using Dojo Build system to build my project and minify the files. I am getting an error during the build and am unable to locate the source. So I want to skip the compilation/optimization step during the build and only need the minification to work.

Is this possible? and if yes, how?

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minification involves compilation, because system actually compiles your JavaScript to internal representation, optimizes this machine-readable form and then outputs it back, generating new JS source from it. Therefore no, you can't minify without compilation.